# How to handle a input into function which can be float or nvarchar (Function parameter is varchar)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a function `[fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters]` which takes phone numbers as input remove any characters other than numeric and returns only numeric part.

Example : if I pass (800)-123-1234 in to the function it removes the non numeric character and returns me 8001231234.

My inputs will be phone number which usually are float datatype. So I used

```
select [dbo].[fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](Ltrim(str(Phone, 50, 0)))
```

to pass through and it used to work fine. But now I am getting `nvarchar` numbers like (800)-123-1234 as a source.

When I am using the above function it's erroring out:

> 'Error converting data type nvarchar to float'

Here is the function which I am using

```
Create Function [dbo].[fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END

    IF (@strText Like '1%')
    BEGIN
        SET @StrText = Stuff(@StrText,1,1,'')
    END        

    RETURN @strText
END
```

How can I handle both `nvarchar` and `float` numbers while passing in to the above function?

Comment: You would seem to have an error in the code in your function.  Perhaps if you included the definition, someone could help.

Comment: So are you saying that you're passing an `nvarchar`-type argument to the `str()` function? That will certainly give you a conversion error if the `nvarchar` can't be converted to a `float`, which is what `str()` expects. And even if it can be converted, why would you do that? You're basically converting a string to a float just so you can convert it back to a string.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the response. Actually I have a stored proc which uses this function .So the source phone number field can be either float data type or nvarchar. I just wanted to handle both data types as inputs.

Comment: Why in the world are you using floats to store phone numbers? Floats are an approximate datatype designed for usage in scientific types of applications. Honestly any type of numeric is kind of silly for phone numbers because you will never need to perform math against a phone number. varchar should be sufficient for phone numbers in any country. One other caveat, if you strip off all non-numeric values how are you going to support country codes?

Comment: Our list is only US numbers . our business people load data from excel,when they load using import export wizard the data type is float .So my process starts once they load the Data in to sql server.

Answer (score 1):

The STR function in sql server ex expecting a float datatype as the first argument and in this case your input is not float datatype , it is a nvarchar type. To solve this problem, i will suggest use the substring function with Cast function. Please find the sample sql below.

select ltrim(Substring(cast(phone_number as nvarchar(100)),0,50)) from test_phone

Here first you change the phone_number data type from float to navrachar and then using sub string you are collecting first 50 character and Ltrim for trimming purpose.

You can try this and hopefully your problem will be fixed.

Note: there are different ways to solve the same problem, the above problem may not be optimized one.

Regards - Sanjeeb

Comment: This is working fine for nvarchar phone numbers ,But when i pass float  numbers now it is giving me wrong results as float numbers are passed with e notation.Example when i pass float value '2038781814' its giving me '203878009'